# Change .xls to .csv without losing columns

Tags: csv, sed, terminal, multiple-columns, xls

I have a folder with around 400 .txt files that I need to convert to .csv. When I batch rename them to .csv, all the columns get smushed together into one. Same thing happens when I convert to .xls then .csv, even though the columns are fine in .xls. If I open the .xls file and save as to .csv, it's fine, but this would require opening all 400 files.

I am working with sed from the mac terminal. After navigating to the folder that contains the files within the terminal, here is some code that did not work:

for file in *.csv; do sed 's/[[:blank:]]+/,/g'

for file in *.csv; do sed -e "s/ /,/g"

for file in *.csv; do s/[[:space:]]/,/g

for file in *.csv; do sed 's/[[:space:]]{1,}/,/g'

Any advice on how to restore the column structure to the csv files would be much appreciated. And it's probably already apparent but I'm a coding newb so please go easy. Thanks!

Edit: here is an example of how the xls columns look, and how they should look in csv format:

```
Dotsc.exe   2/12/15 1:17 PM 0   Nothing 1   Practice
```

Everything that is separated  by spaces here (except the space between 7 and PM) are separated by columns in the file. Here is what it looks like when I rename the batch rename the file to .csv:

Dotsc.exe 2/12/15 1:17 PM 0 Nothing 1 Practice

Columns have now turned into spaces, and all data is in the same column. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Show some sample lines from the input files.

Comment: Not sure how to do that so it will appear to you how it appears to me, but imagine a typical excel file with columns separating the data. The csv files have all the data, except all in one column, so instead of columns separating the data, there are single spaces separating the data. What I believe I need to do is replace those spaces with commas, though I could be wrong.

Comment: _"Not sure how to do that so it will appear to you how it appears to me"_  Select some sample lines and copy-and-paste them into the question.  Then select them with the mouse and select code `{}`.  This will format them literally.

Comment: Tell us in what way the code you posted "did not work". Did it core dump, produce a syntax error, wrong output, no output, or something else? The `sed` commands you list will not write their output back to the original file since you didn't give them the `-i` option, could that be in what way they "did not work"?

Comment: John, thanks for the help, I just edited the post that will hopefully make it more clear. Ed, it didn't work in the sense that absolutely nothing happened. a ">" comes up as the next line in the terminal, and the files remain unchanged. Also tried for file in *.csv; do sed -i "s/ /,/g" with same result.

Comment: @user2461563  _"nothing happened. a ">" comes up as the next"_ That is critical information.  That indicates that the command was incomplete and the shell wants you to finish entering the command.  In this case, it is because the commands that you show are lacking the `done` statement to signal the end of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are trying to do only in batch is not possible . I suggest you to use some library in Java.

Take a look here : http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/

Comment: I did have a programmer do this for me in the past so I know it is possible.

Comment: It sounds absolutely trivial, can't imagine why you'd think it's not possible. We just need to see some sample input and expected output so we can provide the right script for the job.

Comment: ok maybe i I didn't explain it well. What i meant is that of course you can change the file's name but you have to open that file with excel because with a normal editor is not possible. So i believe that you wanted to do that. Sorry for the misunderstanding